# ASP.NET MVC Modal BeginForm Sends Null HtmlAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap Modal to create a new item in database.

I have a page which contains below code. And page url is .../ProjectManager/Projects/1.

I want to pass this id value (in the url) into my modal and then I need to use it in the form. When I run this code, controller method parameter id is coming null.

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="AddModule" data-target="#NewModule">New Module</a>

  <div class="modal fade" id="NewModule" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-left">Add New Module/Submodule</h4>
                </div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("AddModule", "ProjectManager", FormMethod.Post, new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Id"].ToString() }))
                {
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="te">
                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        @Html.Label("Module Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        @Html.Editor("ModuleName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Module</button>
                    </div>

                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddModule(string ModuleName, string id)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Projects");
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have checked and it did not send id parameter to the page. That is what I am asking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of `BeginForm`.

You are using [`BeginForm(HtmlHelper, string, string, FormMethod, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492714(v=vs.118).aspx). You can see on MSDN that the object is `htmlAttributes`, so this sets the `id` of the form element.

You need to use [`BeginForm(HtmlHelper, string, string, object, FormMethod)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933(v=vs.118).aspx). In this overload the object is `routeValues`, which is the one you want.

So you need to swap the parameters round:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddModule", "ProjectManager",
    new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Id"].ToString() },
    FormMethod.Post))
```